# SharePoint Online Noteboard not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-online

On our SharePoint Online site, I added a Noteboard Webpart. However, it is not appearing. Even when I set it to show Title and Border, it is still not appearing.

Anybody else experiencing this?

Comment: Do you mean Notebook?

Comment: I mean the Noteboard Webpart under "Social Collaboration" in the Webparts. It's weird because I have used the Noteboard webpart before but this is the first time that it doesn't appear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Noteboard webpart` seems to have been **deprecated** in SPO. While Microsoft has not given any solid reason to retire these webparts, i believe its because instead of newsfeed its actively promoting Yammer for driving social engagements.

So as per below links, it will still be visible and enabled but it will show up as blank when added to a page.

[SharePoint Online Tags & Notes feature retired](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-Tags-Notes-feature-retired-77851bd5-6d5e-42fe-9bf6-d7c17eeb771f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Microsoft killing some features in Office 365 SharePoint Online](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/09/microsoft-killing-features-office-365-sharepoint-online.html)

PS - Welcome to the cloud first world !

Comment: Yammer seems to be the way forward after my discussion with MS recently.

Answer (score 5):

As gautam said it is retired from SharePoint Online. 
Instead of **Note Board** you can use **Discussion list**.

Hope it will help.